# Any examples of what JVM JIT actually does?

Tags: java, jvm, jit

There's a good overview of [groups of JIT optimisations](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.vm.80.doc/docs/jit_optimize.html), mentioning

- Trivial inlining
- Call graph inlining
- Tail recursion elimination
- Virtual call guard optimizations
- Local data flow analyses and optimizations
- Register usage optimization
- Simplifications of Java idioms
- Code reordering, splitting, and removal
- Loop reduction and inversion
- Loop striding and loop-invariant code motion
- Loop unrolling and peeling
- Loop versioning and specialization
- Exception-directed optimization
- Switch analysis
- Global data flow analyses and optimizations
- Partial redundancy elimination
- Escape analysis
- GC and memory allocation optimizations
- Synchronization optimizations

1) Are there simple examples for each case? An example per answer here will be awesome. But just links to talks/slides/articles are welcome as well.

2) How could JIT changes be visualised, except [logging via PrintAssembly](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/PrintAssembly) in terms "before/after"?

Comment: These are all standard compiler optimizations. Try a book, e.g the Green Dragon book. Too broad.

Comment: e.g. a good detailed article showing how to eliminate out-of-range array access https://darksi.de/d.sea-of-nodes/

Answer (score 5):

Discussion of JVM JIT optimizations is a very broad topic which deserves the whole book. The list you've asked about does not name the particular optimizations; instead each bullet names the whole family of optimizations. Describing each one with examples is a huge work, so don't expect that someone will just do it here for free.

However, here are some useful links to start studying the topic:

- [JVM JIT-compiler overview by Vladimir Ivanov](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~vlivanov/talks/2015_JIT_Overview.pdf)
- [JVM JIT for Dummies by Charles Nutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Yud4Q2HEz4)
- [JIT optimization techniques by Dávid Csákvári](https://advancedweb.hu/2016/05/27/jvm_jit_optimization_techniques/)
- [HotSpot Compiler team wiki](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/PerformanceTechniques)
- [Presentations about HotSpot JVM internals](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/Presentations)

2) There is a tool called Ideal Graph Visualizer. It relies on `-XX:PrintIdealGraphLevel` option which is available in debug builds of HotSpot. [More info »](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/7b671e6b0d5b/src/utils/IdealGraphVisualizer/README.md)

Comment: Thanks for links. The 35th Vladimir's slide contains a really impressive enrolled list of named optimisations! And slides 79-89 are exactly what I was looking for! 

I also wonder how many people just blindly hope that "jit will handle it", and how many are aware of what is actually happening; and want to migrate from 1st to 2nd group :) Feeling like just reading jvm parts is not quite enough.